# Grafana not reading datetime column

Tags: mysql, time-series, grafana

Okay, so I'm new to Grafana, and have loaded several df through MySQL database. 
For the sake of simplicity, let's use a small df (that also doesn't work). Table contains id + 6 columns and 5 rows. Here are the features:

Table: year
Columns:
id int(11) 
year datetime 
Total_GAP int(11) 
Kitchen int(11) 
Laundry int(11) 
Heat_AC int(11) 
Remaining int(11)

The thing is, Grafana reads everything well but the datetime. It automatically converts it into unix time. This is the first row of the variable 'year' in Grafana: 1136073600000. This is how it is in SQL: 2006-01-01 00:00:00.

I realized that if you drop the last three digits from '1136073600000' and I convert the timestamp to date it shows 1/1/2006, 1:00:00 AM (through an online calculator). This would work for me, but I don't know how to do this.

Please let me know if you need more info, and thank you very much in advance!
Try to keep it as simple as you can, since I'm a beginner!

I have tried importing the data into MySQL in different datetime formats, but Grafana shows the same timestamp no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what did it, but creating another user (I only had the default admin) and moving from the "Explore" tab to the "New dashboard" tab did it!